# spring boot with hibernate, I can't take away table name with underscore

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have tried all alternatives in application.properties (see below) I have found so far but my application is still creating the table with "_" instead of camel case as I set up.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

```
1 
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy

output
DefaultNamingStrategy cannot be cast to org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy

2
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
output
org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy cannot be cast to org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy

3
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
output
org.hibernate.SQL                        : drop table tipo_dominio if exists
NOTE: no error but I didn't get the table name without "_"

4
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
output
EJB3NamingStrategy cannot be cast to org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy
```

my entity

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;




@Entity(name="TipoDominio")
@Table(name="TipoDominio")
public class TipoDominio implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
```

pom

```
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>

        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <!-- Compile -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.4.193</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

main

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

*** Edited
I tried

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class
```

without success as well

Answer (score 4):

With SpringBoot 1.5.x the hibernate version is "5.x". This means that the naming strategy classes for tables without underscores has changed. This should work for what you have.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Note that the configuration property name changed as well as the class.

Comment: It works! I tried `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`, `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy`. None of them works!

Answer (score 0):

probably it does so because it creates table without quotes, which for h2 means case insensitive identifier. Do youreally need a case sensitive identifier?